# How can I control my Mac remotely?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best Remote Desktop Application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)

What's the typical way of managing a Mac remotely?

Say I'm at home on a MacBook Pro, I'd like to be able to access my iMac that is at the office. Not just access files, but actually see and perform tasks on its desktop.

Would I use screen sharing or Apple Remote Desktop? Or something else?

*EDIT: This question is NOT the same question as the suggested duplicate. I'm asking specifically about Mac computers, that suggested duplicate is for PCs...so it doesn't answer my question at all.*

Comment: You are probably going to get some responses recommending free software, but keep in mind, since you are accessing a business PC, most require you to buy a paid version. I initially was going to recommend TeamViewer based solely on the title of the question, but then I saw what you wanted to do with it. I am not a MAC expert, so beyond that software, I could not tell you what is best.

Comment: I have no problem paying for software. Just want what will work best.

Comment: Use logmein.com

Comment: Where is the suggested duplicate?... I don't see a link up top.

Comment: Don't edit the duplicate out.

Comment: *ahem* TeamViewer... supports Mac.

Comment: @sathya see http://superuser.com/questions/292904/how-can-i-control-my-mac-remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into System Preferences -> Sharing and enable either Screen Sharing ([VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)) and/or Remote Login ([SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)). Use VNC if you need to use a GUI application, otherwise using SSH is probably preferable. Personally I onlyuse SSH, I very rarely need to use a GUI application remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LogmeIn](http://www.logmein.com).

If you just want to take over the remote machine as if you were sitting in the office, then the free version should do what you want.

If you want to print documents from the office computer to a printer at home, you may need the paid for/PRO version. PRO also allows you to transfer files between the two computers which the free version does not (although there are other ways of doing this, such as dropbox).